# Android how to bind arraylist to textview? I am using prebuilt database.

Tags: android, data-binding, textview

ArrayList q = db.GetAllValues();

```
    for(int i=0;i<.size();i++)
    {
         String text1 = q.get(i).toString();
         author.setText(text1);
```

Comment: // This will return a list containing all the database records
 public ArrayList<Q> GetAllValues()
 {
  Cursor c;
  ArrayList<Qs list = new ArrayList<Q>();
  c = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  if (c.moveToFirst())
  {
   do
   {
    Q q = new Q();
    q.setID(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
    q.setAuthor(c.getString(1));
    q.setphoto(c.getBlob(2)); 
    list.add(quotes);

   }
   while (c.moveToNext());
  }
  if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) 
  {
   c.close();
  }
  myDataBase.close();
  return list;
 }

Comment: you should edit your question instead of posting this information as a comment. additionally, you should add information on what you expected and what your current result is. if it's just to add all your data-base entries to the textview and display them there, meaning your result is to get only the last entry, and everything else works fine , you should go with the answer provided by Evan Li

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to show all elements of the ArrayList in the textview. Then you can use a StringBuilder to combine all elements into one string, the set this string to the textview.

Use StringBuilder will significantly improve performance of string merging.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i ++) {
    sb.append(q.get(i).toString();
}
author.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I want to show a slideshow. I am planning to display records from first row and keep moving on. I want to implement it. I am able to  store and fetch all the records in array-list. I want to know how to implement the binding of arraylist with textview /images?

Comment: Then you might use Gallery widget.

Comment: Gallery widget is deprecated. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: You may check HorizontalScrollView, ScrollView or ListView.